# Additive Chaining with named_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

Is there a way to combine scopes in an additive fashion?

If I have the scopes

```
User.big_haired
```

and

```
User.plays_guitar
```

I can call

```
User.big_haired.plays_guitar
```

and get all the users who have big hair AND play guitar.  Can I write this to get all users who have big hair OR play guitar?

I guess I have to add that I realize that you can run a set of queries and add the results together.  That's what I'm trying not to do.

Answer (score 2):

So you have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :big_haired, :conditions => {:hair => 'massive'}
  named_scope :plays_guitar, :conditions => {:plays => 'guitar'}
end
```

User.big_haired.plays_guitar => Lots of users.

I am unaware of a method to mash the two together.  Perhaps just blending the arrays:

```
@users = (User.big_haired + User.plays_guitar).uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Searchlogic, it recently [supports combining named scopes with OR](http://www.binarylogic.com/2009/08/26/using-searchlogic-to-combine-named-scopes-with-or/)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out on some of my models that have named_scopes defined.  It will put the conditions together as an AND condition if you combine it.  So...

```
User.big_haired.plays_guitar
```

will result in (obviously my shorthand SQL, not the real rails generated stuff)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hair = 'massive' AND plays = 'guitar'
```

I don't know of a way to combine them as an OR relationship.  That would be incredibly complex to mix in when you think about the various options.  We chain named_scopes all the time, it works well (as long as you want them ANDed together).

To do the and case, I would either create a special named scope with the OR conditions built on, or use a union to produce a unique set like so:

```
User.big_haired | User.plays_guitar
```